# PeopleSoft delivered code JPM_JP_ITEMS

Tags: peoplesoft

I update a record into JPM_JP_ITEMS table and I would like to capture and do some thing inside the SavePostChange event. Inside the SavePostChange event, I am unable to detect if the row is new or not. Since this is update the &Row.IsNew should be false. Is there a way to detect if this is update operation?

Here is my code..

```
Local Record &Rec = GetRecord();
Local Row &Row = GetRow();
If (&Row.IsNew) Then
 /* do insert related stuff*/
else
/* do update related stuff */
End-If;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the isChanged property of Row class, returning true if you update some data on the related row.

Comment: Telkarion, Have you tried it??.. isChanged property is not working in this case.